# Daterangepicker - change end date only (Start date wont change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker. All works fine. http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Now, need to know whether is it possible to change only end date of selection to early or later?? Start date will be in selected state.

Ex: http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/sg/homepage  (Book flight - return trip)

**HTML:**

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="tripOne" name="tripOne" />
```

**JS:**

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var maxLimitDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear() + 1, nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('input[name="tripOne"]').daterangepicker({
  "autoApply": true,
    "autoUpdateInput": false,
    "minDate": today,
    "maxDate": maxLimitDate,
    "locale": {
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
    }
}, function (start, end) {
   $("#tripOne").val(start.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
});
```